# Cloud9`s terminal works slowly

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, cloud9

Started using the [Cloud9](http://c9.io), for small practices with Nodejs, my apps are always very simple.

I noticed, that on the first time I launched the workspace, terminal works fine and responds immediately. But after a few executions or few minutes, it starts freezing and my typing responds in a few seconds, but not immediatelly.

I am using the free account. But my performance(CPU, RAM) parameters(in the top right corner) are absolutley okay.

So is it a c9.io server trouble? Or it is about javascript in my browser? And how can I make my work easier there?

updt1: Text editor area and workplace navigation area works absolutley fine. The only thing works badly - terminal.

updt2: When I am opening a new Terminal it works fast again.

Comment: it's your internet speed or your browser problem. Rest c9.io works fine.

Comment: @Nivesh I`m not sure about Internet speed. When I am opening a new Terminal it works fast again...

Comment: If something like this happens again then you're best opening a topic in the [Cloud9 community](https://community.c9.io) and including any errors or messages you see in the [browser console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and noticed when the terminal was freezing, there was a message "Updating Git..." in the lower left of the screen. Anytime git does an auto-refresh, it seems to hang up the terminal. If you don't need the git autorefresh feature, you can turn it off as follows.

In Preferences, look under Extensions / Git, there is a setting "Git: Autorefresh". Turn it off.

Ideally, this is something AWS should be able to fix. This is just a work-around.